# Unable to establish remote access to workplace pc windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, remote-desktop

I am successfully connected to my workplace via vpn. But when I try to connect to my pc via remote desktop it keep asking for credentials even I am providing the right one. This works fine in windows xp but unable to connect using win 7. Also after establishing a vpn I lost my internet access.

Any idea.

Comment: This would probably be better suited for SuperUser or ServerFault forums.

Comment: Choosing SF as corporate firewalls etc may be a factor, but 50/50 could also have gone SU.

Comment: There is an option to use the vpn provided gateway (no idea what the exact english wording of the optinon is, i currently only have access to a german windows instalation). If you uncheck that option, your regular internet traffic will still be routed through your internet connection and not through the vpn. Depending on the size of the network you are vpn-ing into, you might not be able to reach part of that network. choose the lesser of those two evils :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fully qualifying your user name i.e. `DOMAIN\user` or `user@domain` ?

As far as the VPN your Networking guys probably don't have split tunneling enabled. Nothing you can do about that from your side. You could try asking nicely for them to give you a VPN profile that has split tunneling enabled.